# Viewing video or gif summary on tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to view a video or animated gif under image summaries on tensorflow's tensorboard? For example, can you pass a sequence of image tensors and display an animated gif?

Comment: It's marked as "Contributions Welcome" at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3936

Answer (score 2):

Video summaries are not currently implemented in TensorBoard, but (as Yaroslav points out) there is a [feature request open](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/39) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that tensorboardX supports videos now [link](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorboard.html#tensorboardX.SummaryWriter.add_video). However, I do not see it in the tensorflow tensorboard documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary). Is is supported or not in TF2?

Answer (score 0):

For all those who find this question unanswered:

#### for tensorflow users

As of January 2024 I could not find video support at the tensorflow tensorboard [code base](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary):

[image]

#### for pytorch users

The good news is, however, that pytorch users do have support for this feature. See the docs [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_video) and here a short example:

```py
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter()
# vid_tensor: (N,T,C,H,W). The values should lie in [0, 255] for type uint8 or [0, 1] for type float.
writer.add_video(tag, vid_tensor, global_step=None, fps=4, walltime=None)
```